# Extjs MVVM - Slider widget change event

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm

In the MVVM structure I am very confused of how can I trigger some functions in the controller from some view elements. Handlers for buttons and some simple things are working, but here I have an example, which I couldn't figure out properly.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qcf

Or see

```
Ext.define('MVVM.view.Master', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype  : 'mvvm-MasterView',
requires: [
    'Ext.grid.column.Action',
    'Ext.ProgressBarWidget',
    'Ext.slider.Widget',
    'Ext.sparkline.*'
],

title : 'Master Panel',

store : 'People',

columns: [
    { 
        text      : 'Name',  
        dataIndex : 'name' 
    },{
        text     : 'Slider',
        xtype    : 'widgetcolumn',
        width    : 120,
        dataIndex: 'progress',
        widget: {
            xtype: 'sliderwidget',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 1,
            decimalPrecision: 2,
            listeners: {
                change: function(slider, value) {
                        //how to trigger something in the controller?

                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
    },        
    { 
        text      : 'Email', 
        dataIndex : 'email', 
        flex      : 1 
    },
    { 
        text      : 'Phone',
        dataIndex : 'phone' 
    }
]
```

});

Every time the slider changes, I need to call a function in the controller. How to do that?

This doesn't work:

```
listeners: {
                    change: 'controllerFunction'
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a normal Controller rather than a ViewController then you can do something like this:

`var controller  =   MyApp.app.getController('MyApp.controller.MainController');
controller.doMethod();`

If you mean a View Controller then this article is very useful:

https://www.sencha.com/blog/using-viewcontrollers-in-ext-js-5/

Comment: Yes, this works, just I don't know the controller name from the view... 
MyApp.app.getController('MyApp.controller.MainController');

I posted this quite some time ago, have to check maybe I found already some solution.

Comment: ok, sure. The controller name is as it is defined at the top of the controller file and shouldn't change e.g. you should know which controller has the method you want in it. The only difference would be if you're using ViewControllers instead, which case a slightly different approach is needed.